# How to work with this form in Django?

Tags: python, django

Normally when I want to display individual form fields I use:

```
{{ form.NAMEOFFIELD }}
```

and if I want to display the entire form I just do:

```
{{ form }}
```

But now I'm working on a file where that doesn't work. The backend developers might not have made the form view specific so the only way I can display it is by doing:

```
{% render_comment_form for object.video %}
```

For this form, how can I grab individual field and catch form errors (since it's not called the usual way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're talking about the comments app. As well as `render_comment_form`, that app provides a [`get_comment_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/comments/#rendering-a-custom-comment-form) tag:

```
{% get_comment_form for object.video as comment_form %}
```

Now the form is available in the `comment_form` variable, and can be iterated in the normal way.